# AppCompatActivity actionbar and device menu button

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using AppCompatActivity with ActionBar style `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar`. When I create menu from activity, than overflow menu button appear in ActionBar, if device don't have hardware menu button.
But, on device Xiaomi Redmi Note, overflow button apear in ActionBar, and device has own hardware button. 
This is some configs:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

Comment: The overflow menu button will appear whether the device has a hardware menu button or not. I have a Galaxy Note 3 and Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 Ed and they both showed the overflow button since version 22 (I think) of the compat library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appcompat-v7 support library forces the overflow menu to be always visible in the action bar (or toolbar) for every device with KitKat and higher. The MENU key, if it exists, will still work, opening the overflow menu. It is a desired behavior and it's designed to be like this.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
public boolean showsOverflowMenuButton() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return !ViewConfigurationCompat.hasPermanentMenuKey(ViewConfiguration.get(mContext));
    }
}
```

You can see full source code here:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/view/ActionBarPolicy.java#L49-L55

Comment: Thank you. I thought that it's bug)